# Like button in news pages appears only sometimes in SharePoint Online classic experience

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list

We migrated our Intranet from SharePoint 2016 to SharePoint Online by doing a lift and shift. Meaning that the Intranet it's still in classic experience. We are facing now an issue with the like/rating functionality. The like button/number of likes is appearing only sometimes.
The list "Pages" is set to "Classic experience" and also the likes feature is activated.

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that "Number of Likes" column missing sometimes?
[image]

Do you have multiple views set on the Pages library? Make sure Number of Likes column has been checked to display in the view.
[image]